# setRequestInterception(false) returns an error

Tags: puppeteer

I'm using puppeteer to scrape a number of sites. The requirements for each site are different. I trying to use `page.setRequestInterception(true);` for some sites and then turn off for other sites. The example below starts `page.setRequestInterception(true);` but causes the error `Error: Request Interception is not enabled!` when I run `await page.setRequestInterception(false);`. What am I doing wrong?

Path: `Controller`

```
async function controller(page, logger) {
  await page.setRequestInterception(true);
  page.on('request', (req) => {
    if (
      req.resourceType() == 'stylesheet' ||
      req.resourceType() == 'font' ||
      req.resourceType() == 'image'
    ) {
      req.abort();
    } else {
      req.continue();
    }
  });

  await Promise.all([
    page.waitForNavigation(),
    page.goto('https://site-one.com')
  ]);

  await page.setRequestInterception(false);

  await Promise.all([
    page.waitForNavigation(),
    page.goto('https://site-two.com')
  ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error is produced not by the `await page.setRequestInterception(false);` call but by `'request'` event handler after interseption is toggled off. You need to cansel the event listener as well. See the last example [in the `page` class intro](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#class-page).